# Synchronize a computation of 2 and more Futures

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, future

I found out that I can't figure out how to synchronize a computation of 2 and more `Futures`:

```
val fs = List(1, 2, 3) map { x => Future { /* some computation depending on x... */ } }
fs(0) onComplete {
  case Success(x) => 
    fs(1) onComplete { 
      case Success(x) => 
        fs(2) onComplete ....
}
```

That doesn't look sensible.

I want to get all the values from the `fs`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Future.sequence` to convert your `List[Future]` to a `Future[List]`:

```
val fs = List(1, 2, 3) map { x => Future(x * x) }
val f = Future.sequence(fs)
f.onComplete(println(_))
```

Will print `Success(List(1, 4, 9))`

Comment: Note 'onComplete' and the codes inside it (`println(_)`) will not run on the main thread. and could make problems in some use cases.

Answer (score 9):

Use `Future.traverse`

```
val inList = List(1, 2, 3)
val fs = Future.traverse(inList) { x =>
  Future {
    /* some computation depending on x... */
  }
}

fs onSuccess { case outList => 
  ...
}
```

This will fail if *any* of the elements fails.

If you want all the results, regardless of failure or success, then the nicest way is to `recover` them, wrapping results in instances of `Try`:

```
def asyncFunc(i: Int): Future[String] = ...

val inList = List(1, 2, 3)
val rawResults = inList.map(asyncFunc)
val recoveredResults = rawResults.map(Success(_)).recover(case x => Failure(x))

val completedResults = Future.sequence(recoveredResults)

completedResults onSuccess { case outList =>
  outList map {
    case Success(s) => ...
    case Failure(t) => ...
  }
}
```

*hint: If you do this sort of thing much, it's generally easier to make sure that **all** your asynchronous methods complete sucessfully with an instance of `Future[Try[T]]`, rather than having any error embedded in the `Future`*

Something like this:

```
def slowFunc(i: Int): String = ...
def asyncFunc(i: Int): Future[Try[String]] = Future { Try { slowFunc(i) } }

val inList = List(1, 2, 3)
val results = Future.traverse(inList)(asyncFunc)

results onSuccess { case outList =>
  outList map {
    case Success(s) => ...
    case Failure(t) => ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper method for this in the Future companion object:

```
val fs: List[Future[Int]] = List(1, 2, 3) map { x => Future { /* some computation depending on x... */ } }
val allFs: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(fs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `for` statement for that.

```
val f1 : Future[A] = Future { /* whatever */ }
val f2 : Future[B] = Future { /* whatever */ }
val results : Future[(A,B)] = for {
   f1Result <- f1
   f2Result <- f2
} yield(f1Result, f2Result)
```

It is important to start both futures (f1 and f2) before the `for` statement otherwise the second future will wait the first one finish.

Comment: There's a trick to avoid having to declare the futures outside of the for comprehension, I've described it here: http://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-protips-2.html